# Почему поле пустое? yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Поле `var_dump($user);` вывод:

```
object(app\models\User)#112 (15) { ["id"]=> NULL ["username"]=> NULL ["password"]=> NULL ["authKey"]=> NULL ["accessToken"]=> NULL ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$13$E6oSQlgwHROnPQKu/KfHq.3Z5FpPGWys4lp4wqNchYuE82ZWgkOn2" ["auth_key"]=> string(32) "wQJcxKnXbVFURdWXHQncPY5wwBOQu4L4" ["token"]=> string(43) "aB-advFKsGdC0ZPHiJd63f6aItUF9-fv_1534357898" ["email"]=> string(16) "admin@myblog.loc" } ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["username"]=> string(5) "admin" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$13$E6oSQlgwHROnPQKu/KfHq.3Z5FpPGWys4lp4wqNchYuE82ZWgkOn2" ["auth_key"]=> string(32) "wQJcxKnXbVFURdWXHQncPY5wwBOQu4L4" ["token"]=> string(43) "aB-advFKsGdC0ZPHiJd63f6aItUF9-fv_1534357898" ["email"]=> string(16) "admin@myblog.loc" } ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_relationsDependencies":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=> array(0) { } ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=> NULL ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=> string(7) "default" ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

Поле `var_dump($this->password);` вывод `NULL`.

> **Почему `NULL`?**

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего этот экземпляр был создан без переданных в конструктор модели массива `[attribute => value]`(`new User($arr)`). А по дефолту в yii2, если свойство модели не просетить, то при попытке вывести значение свойства, будет выводиться `null`(как указатель на то, что свойство еще не задали).

Comment: Нашел проблему...в модели поля таблицы были объявлены как public-переменные. Не знал что модель это сама делает. Убрал объявления, все заработало.